# Merge array of object dynamically with same key and create it as new data (array of object)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, filter, array-merge, arrayobject

Ive got some array of object
I want to merge array of object with the same key and create it as new object based on the key and value

```
const data =[{
  date:"19",
  status:"in",
hour:”12:00”

},{

  date:"19",
  status:"in",
hour:”12:20”
},{
  date:"19",
  status:"in",
hour:”12:43”
},{
  date:"19",
  status:"out",
hour:”16:16”

},{
  date:"20",
  status:"in",
hour:07:30”
},{
  date:"20",
  status:"out",
hour:”14:40”
},{
  date:"21",
  status:"in",
hour:”08:12”
}
]
```

Here is the result that i want

```
result =[{
date:”19”,
hourIn= “12:00”,
hourOut= “16:16”,      
}, {
  date:"20",
  hourIn:"07:30",
hourOut:14:40”
},{
  date:"21",
hourIn:”08:12”,
hourOut:”-“}]
```

How i suppose to solve this problem ?

Comment: It would be very easy to do if you had the `"status: "in"` and `"status": "out"` in different arrays. 

My concern is that it will be very difficult to not just overwrite the `"in"` with whatever the last one is while also preserving the latest `"out"`

Comment: Yeah youre right, but the problem is my backend engineer didnt settle like that and didnt want -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it,
I iterated through the `data`, checking if that date had already been passed.

If not, I checked if the `status` was `in` or `out`, then set the `hour` and the `date`.

If it had been passed, I checked the `status`, then checked if the hour was earlier than the `hourIn` or later than the `hourOut` already set.

```js
let result={};
const data=[{date:"19",status:"in",hour:"12: 00"},{date:"19",status:"in",hour:"12:20"},{date:"19",status:"in",hour:"12:43"},{date:"19",status:"out",hour:"16:16"},{date:"20",status:"in",hour:"07:30"},{date:"20",status:"out",hour:"14:40"},{date:"21",status:"in",hour:"08:12"}];

data.forEach(({ date, status, hour }) => {
  if (date in result) {
    if (status == 'in' && hour < result[date].hourIn) result[date].hourIn = hour;
    else if (status == 'out' && hour > result[date].hourOut) result[date].hourOut = hour;
  } else result[date] = {
    date,
    hourIn: status == 'in' ? hour : '-',
    hourOut: status == 'out' ? hour : '-'
  };
});

result = Object.values(result);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to achieve a mini MapReduce. You can google for more details.

1. Create a Map where the key is your date and the value is an array of objects with the same date.
2. Now segregate all the objects date-wise by inserting them into the Map.
3. Sort the array based on in,out as first criteria and time as second criteria. So in every array first object will be first in time and last object will be last out time.
4. reduce every array into an object take the first & last objects.

   let map = new Map();

   for(let d of data){
   let t = map.get(d.date)||[];
   t.push(d);
   map.set(d.date,t);
   }

   for(let v of map.values()){
   v.sort((a,b)=>a.status < b.status || timecmp(a.hour,b.hour)) // implement timecmp
   }

   let result = []

   for(let v of map.values()){
   let reduced = // get it from v[0] v[v.length-1]
   result.push(reduced);
   }

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've done this I'm not sure it adds much, but here's a way using reduce:

```js
const data = [
  {date:"19",status:"in",hour:"12:00"}, {date:"19",status:"in",hour:"12:20"}, {date:"19",status:"in",hour:"12:43"}, {date:"19",status:"out",hour:"16:16"},
  {date:"20",status:"in",hour:"07:30"}, {date:"20",status:"out",hour:"14:40"},
  {date:"21",status:"in",hour:"08:12"}
];

const new_hour = (field, status, current, new_val) =>
  field === status &&
    (
      current === '-' ||
      (status === 'in') === (new_val < current)
    ) ? new_val : current;

const hours_reducer = (acc, { date, status, hour }) =>
  Object.assign(acc, {
    [date]: {
      date,
      hourIn: new_hour('in', status, acc[date]?.hourIn || '-', hour),
      hourOut: new_hour('out', status, acc[date]?.hourOut || '-', hour),
    }
  });

const values = Object.values( data.reduce(hours_reducer, {}) );

console.log(values);
```